# You can’t open the application because it is not supported on this type of Mac

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I am currently working on a text message application on xcode and when I try to open the project again, I keep getting the error message "You can’t open the application "ChatPractice" because it is not supported on this type of Mac." Below is a picture of what it looks like on my desktop. There are also no xcode projects when I try to open it from my Finder. It is now a .momd file with some random files in it and I don't know what they are and how my xcode project became this way. Is there anyway to recover my xcode project?

[image: These are the files in my project]
[image: This is what my xcode project looks right now on my desktop]

Comment: Are you using source control (like git)?

Comment: You're looking inside the built app, not inside the Xcode project. There's no way to back track from what you have to an Xcode project, unfortunately.